# Running multiple parallel jobs inside threads in python3

Tags: parallel-processing, python-3.6, python-multithreading, joblib

I have two functions `func1()` and `func2()` which are **independent** of each other and can be run in two threads. I am using the `threading` library in `python3` for running these two threads. But inside `func1()`, I am **also** running `for` loops in parallel using `joblib`. So using threading as well as joblib gives the following warning -

`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py:547: UserWarning: Multiprocessing-backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads, setting n_jobs=1`,

and then the for loops inside `func1()` just run sequentially.

Following is the example of the code snippet:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import threading
from math import sqrt

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sample, type):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.type = type
        self.sample = sample
    def run(self):
        if self.type=='func1':
            self.sample.func1()
        else:
            self.sample.func2()

class Sample:
   def func1(self):
       print('this function runs for loop in parallel.')
       ans = Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(sqrt)(i**2) for i in range(1000)) 

   def func2(self):
       print('this function runs sequentially.')

   def try(self):    
       thread1 = MyThread(self, 'func1')
       thread2 = MyThread(self, 'func2')

       thread1.start()
       thread2.start()

       thread1.join()
       thread2.join()

       print('Done...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Sample()
    s.try()
```

How can I solve this problem? Or if its a joblib issue, is there any other library that can be used in place of joblib?

Comment: __show us some of the code you have written__ then we are able to solve  your problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Community rules define, that a high quality question should always explain both **[A] :** one's target ( define what one considers as an acceptable solution ), **best in a format of an MCVE - **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample of such a code + data, that can run & live-demonstrate a **P**roblem-**u**nder-**R**eview. **[B] :** but also tell others all **What Have You Tried So Far** -- i.e. what efforts one has spent so far to analyse & test it -- So, you might want to rather update your post, so as to better meet the Community Rules and Best Practices.